# Restrict upload to display only csvfiles, in php

Tags: php, csv

I have an application which uploads data from a csv file and this is working fine. It would be useful, but not essential, if I could limit the dialog window to only show csv files, and if possible a file template say 'abc*.csv'.

The attached  image shows an example of a dialog box which will only allow files that start with abc*.csv

[Example of csv image dialog box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imyMc.jpg)

Thanks

Harry

Comment: You could use plain html to only allow .csv extension `<input type="file" name="yourname" accept=".csv">`

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you're handling the uploads.
You can either use plain HTML to filter the `.csv` extension or handle it using PHP, or both.

Using HTML:

```
<input type="file" name="upload" accept=".csv">
```

Using PHP:

```
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if( $ext !== 'csv' ) {
    echo 'Invalid extension.';
}
```

Note that this only verifies the extension and not the actual filetype.

Also the [accept](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-accept) attribute of the `<input type="file">` does indeed provider a filter in the file select dialog.

Comment: Ideally, you should use both front end and back end validation in order to prevent users from being able to pass invalid data through the back end.  The last thing you need is invalid data saved to a database